# How to send an http request with parameters to rails from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, http

I'm attempting to test a sample project at

```
http://162.243.232.223:3000/api/query
```

This is a rails project.

The rails controller is looking for a params hash like params[:query]['input']

In javascript, I am using jquery like this:

```
$.get('http://162.243.232.223:3000/api/query')
```

which get the expected default output.

However, I'd like to send in my own params more along the lines of this:

```
$.get('http://162.243.232.223:3000/api/query', { 'input': 'my_input' })
```

However, for whatever reason, this is returning errors, the

```
{ 'input': 'my_input' }
```

argument is not being passed as

```
params[:query]['input']
```

into Rails.

Any ideas on how I could start getting non-default responses back from Rails?

Thanks

Comment: Open up your console and take a look at what _URL_ is actually being fetched by the browser; this will let you know which side the problem is on

Comment: does your server-side rewriting support arbitrary arguments like that? just because you slap any extra key=value pairs into a query string you want doesn't mean it'll actually make it through to your code on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it now you would access it simply with `params[:input]`. The `params` hash gets all path, get and post variables in a single hash.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases when the server is not getting the input params like this how you had mentioned you need to apply this instead:

```
$.param({
        json: JSON.stringify({
            'input': 'my_input'
        })
    });
```